# Clear input values

Tags: html, jsp, servlets

Data comes from a Servlet to HTML input field in a JSP page. When I press `<input type="reset">`, the data is not cleared. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML reset buttons do not clear the fields in the form; they reset the fields back to their initial values (see [example](http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms13.htm)).

If you want to actually clear the data, you'll need to write a specific server-side controller to do that, or use javascript.